# SQL SERVER 2008 Cursor Problem

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I have a table that has some missing values for certain transactions.  The value for a particular transaction is going to depend on the value of all preceding transactions.  Because the preceding nulls need to be populated before the next value can be calculated, I didn't see a good way of writing this as a single query and instead went with a cursor.

In the row_type field a row with a 17 is a transfer from, and a value of 18 is transfer to.  The carrier_id of these two corresponding rows will never match and the amounts will always be opposite sign of each other.

Indexes are good on the table, and overall the execution time isn't bad, it's just that we need to do this on 20 million rows in a batch operation.  I've also looked at using an array based variable, but I think that might be even uglier than the cursor.

The one other thing that I haven't shown here, and may end up being the best result, is to add a modulus parameter, use that to filter by charge_id, and then execute the same cursor in parallel as each individual execution uses up a tiny fraction of the server's resources.

This is a table example for one particular charge_id.

```
trx_type    row_type trx_id carr_ID post_date   Amount
charge      11      15979   550 2012-10-17  92.00
Payment     13      34224   550 2012-10-17  -30.69
Adjustment  15      34225   550 2012-10-17  -53.64
Transfer    17      34226   550 2012-10-17  -7.67(originally NULL)
Transfer    19      34226   210 2012-10-17   7.67(originally NULL)
```

Cursor:

```
DECLARE @transaction_id int
DECLARE @transaction_date datetime
DECLARE @charge_id int
DECLARE @dataset varchar(50)
DECLARE @carrier_id varchar(50)
DECLARE @amount float

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT
    transaction_id,
    post_date,
    charge_id,
    dataset,
    ins1_ID
FROM .dbo.transaction_details
WHERE row_type = 17 AND amount is null
ORDER BY transaction_id

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @transaction_id, @transaction_date, @charge_id, @dataset, @carrier_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

    SELECT
        @amount = coalesce(SUM(amount),0)
    FROM
        .dbo.Transaction_Details t1
    WHERE
        t1.dataset = @dataset AND
        t1.Charge_id = @charge_id AND
        (
        t1.post_date < @transaction_date OR
        (
            t1.post_date = @transaction_date AND
            t1.transaction_id < @transaction_id
        )
        ) AND
        t1.Ins1_ID = @carrier_id

    UPDATE
        .dbo.Transaction_Details
    SET
        amount = CASE
                    WHEN row_type IN (17,20) THEN -1 * @amount
                    WHEN row_type IN (19,18) THEN @amount
                END
    WHERE
        dataset = @dataset AND
        transaction_id = @transaction_id AND
        row_type between 17 and 20


FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @transaction_id, @transaction_date, @charge_id, @dataset, @carrier_id
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: ***WHY OH WHY*** a cursor for something as simple as this?? Use a CTE and a **proper, set-based** approach to **AVOID** cursors altogether!

Comment: I've actually never written a CTE before, which is why it hadn't occurred to me to use one.  Since you suggested it, I'll do some learning and see if I can find a way to re-write it as one.

Comment: Thanks a lot marc_s.  I re-wrote this as a cte and query time went from 4 hours to 2 minutes.  I still have some QA work to make sure that everything calculated correctly, but if so I'll post the full solution tonight.

Comment: the best way to tune a cursor is to get rid of it :-) That keeps coming back as a recurring insight over and over again! :-) Great to hear you got your performance to a useful level!

Comment: Hi @john, mind sharing how you tuned your query using CTE this time?